# Router not firing .find or .findByID in express app. Using nextjs as well

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am using a NextJS/MERN stack.  My NextJS is using my server.js file, along with importing the routes for my API.  The routes appear to be working as they do show activity when firing an API call from Postman or the browser.  However, this is where the activity stops.  It's not getting passed the Model.find() function as far as I can tell.  I am not sure if this has to do with Next js and the prepare method in the server.js, or if this is related to the bodyparser issue.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const urlObject = require('./baseURL')
const passport = require("./nextexpress/config/passport-setup");
const passportSetup = require("./nextexpress/config/passport-setup");
const session = require("express-session");
const authRoutes = require("./nextexpress/routes/auth-routes");
const KBRoutes = require("./nextexpress/routes/kb-routes");
const userRoutes = require('./nextexpress/routes/user-routes')
const pollRoutes = require('./nextexpress/routes/poll-routes')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"); // parse cookie header
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nextapp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextapp.getRequestHandler()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/kb', { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/kb')
console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
const connection = mongoose.connection;
const baseURL = urlObject.baseURL

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

nextapp.prepare().then(() => {
    const app = express();

    console.log(process.env.PORT, '----port here ----')
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
    app.use("/api/kb", KBRoutes);
    app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)
    app.use('/api/poll', pollRoutes)
    app.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {

        return nextapp.render(req, res, '/article', { id: req.params.id })
    })
    app.get('/redirect/:id', (req, res) => {

        return nextapp.render(req, res, '/redirect')
    })

    app.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })

    app.listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    })
})



// connect react to nodejs express server
```

And the relevant route:

```
KBRoutes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(KB.Model)
    KB.find({}, (err, photos) => {
        res.json(kbs)
    })
})
```

I am able to get to each one of the routes.  Before this was working, when I had the NextJS React portion split into a separate domain therefore separate server.js files.  Once I introduced NextJs thats when this problem arose.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the relevant route is trying to return json(kbs), but kbs doesn't seem to be defined. Returning the result of your find query would make more sense to me, including a nice error catcher and some status for good practice. Catching errors should tell you what's going wrong, i would expect an error in your console anyway that would help us out finding the answer even more.

```
KB.find({}, (err, photos) => {
    if (err) res.status(401).send(err)
    res.status(200).json(photos)
})
```